# Which is better, DEM or Triangles (TIN/Terrain)

Tags: dem, terrain, tin

Which is better DEM or TIN?

What are the benefits/negatives of each?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is all very dependent on your needs. You know that TIN is a vector-based representation whereas DEM is represented as a raster from grid of squares. Actually TIN is a type of DEM and derived from the raster DEM.

The TIN representation has information about altitude, slope and aspect and you can use them to extract the areas you require.

There is an information [here](http://www.casa.arizona.edu/data/rnr_420/lecture_pdfs/lect4_TINs.pdf) about TIN and raster DEM.

Raster DEM and TIN examples:

[image: raster dem vs tins]

**Why You Might Want to Use a TIN**

(From http://www.srnr.arizona.edu/rnr/rnr420/dem2/tsld006.htm)

> **Raster DEM**
>
> Data redundancy in areas of uniform terrain
>
> Inability to adapt to areas of differing relief complexity
>
> Exaggerated emphasis along the axis of the grid
>
> **TIN**
>
> Non-redundant data
>
> Allows extra data in complex areas and less data in non-complex areas
>
> The ability to use natural features as break-lines
>
> Of course, you have to like triangles

I hope it helps you..

Comment: thanks, also which would be better for creating a relief map?

Comment: TINs can also be created from elevation points, without first creating a DEM.

Comment: Two of them will have some errors due to surface of earth. But TIN is less error than DEM. When dem has a regular grid, TIN has non-overlapping triangles(irregular network of triangles) which fit better to the Earth surface.

Comment: Any DEM or TIN is as good as your input data. Any other information than your input data is an interpolation. In order to assess, which form of data suits your needs better, you need to understand how it is created and what processes it involves, then you'll know best. Usually my opinion is, that TIN will be more accurate. However depending on your workflow it may be  more difficult to handle it, as there is more tools to work with raster data than with TIN. Both of those data systems have their pros and cons.

Comment: @Aragon, comment below is merely an opinion. The pictures from examples may give a wrong impression, as it seems that raster is more detailed than TIN in this example, which should not be the case when compare those two. Also in some cases raster may (consider that raster is left and TIN is right) have appearance like TIN, when TIN is converted to raster. At least when both datasets were made of the same input data, it should be indicated what interpolation technics were applied to both datasets. Probably shadding and colours should match either.

Comment: @Tomek, thanks your opinion. While agreeing what you say, I put images to tell that TINs has vectorized structure whereas DEM has not... people who already reads details will understand that TIN has a complex structure from raster DEM. but really being a big problem, i can remove it...

Comment: I can also add: DEM is easier and faster in processing. There are already many tools for DEM to perform analytic tasks. On the other hand TIN usually is more precise and should be used for such tasks as calculation of volumes (in engineering calcs).

Comment: @whuber thank your advice but i add information when i want to assist my opinion with any material from other source as usual. Only one thing is that i don't write full address, i write credit with its link under "here" word instead. If i have to write address with full link i can write it which not problem for me but the full link is not seemed good. Nevertheless thanks. Next time i will consider your address but mentioning to plagiarism is not good for me.

Comment: Aragon, thank you for pointing that out. I will delete my comment. Even though I was looking for a link in your post, it was not apparent: the word "here" just doesn't show it well. May I suggest a slight change of approach for your future posts? Name the source of the material. In this case, you could write "The following information is from a [University of Arizona](http://www.srnr.arizona.edu/rnr/rnr420/dem2/tsld001.htm) slide presentation."  That will be a much clearer attribution of the source of your material and will be present even in printouts and bad displays :-).